# how to inject factory into another factory in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two modules and factories in both, and I need to implement factory from the first module into another module.

```
angular.module('APIs', [])

.value  ("myValue"  , "12345")
.factory('apiUrl',['config','url',apiUrl])

function apiUrl(config,url){

}

angular.module('users.service', ['APIs'])

.factory('userService',['myValue',userService])

function userService(apiUrl,myValue){

    //login function
    function login(){
        console.log('myValue',myValue)
        console.log('loginUrl',apiUrl)
    }

    return {
        login:login

    }
}
```

notice: no problem when I inject myValue, but the problem in APIs Factory

and my log:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=urlProvider%20%3C-%20url%20%3C-%20apiUrl%20%3C-%20userService
>       at Error (native)

and sorry for my English.

Comment: The error link -- https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=urlProvider%20%3C-%20url%20%3C-%20apiUrl%20%3C-%20userService The error message says the `url`  service is undefined. Where are you defining the `url` service?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. If you create `factory` use `angular.module('app').factory()`. If you create `service` use `angular.module('app').service()`
2. Always try to have same module name. It is easier later, when you have big application, because of dependency injection.
3. Try to keep files separately, and concatenate it later, for example using `gulp` `gulp-concat`
4. Try to keep all you configuration in `app.js` file and, when you concatenating file, remember, this file should be on top.
5. I would keep values and constants in `app.js` file or would create new file like `factory` or `service` and include it, same as I injected it below.

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', [
        // other module
    ]);

    app.value('myValue', '12345');

    app.constant('myConst', 'some_constant');

    app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    }]);

}());
```

**factory.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('apiUrlFactory', apiUrlFactory);

    apiUrlFactory.$inject = [];

    function apiUrlFactory() {

        var self = this;

        self.url = 'some_url';

        return self;

    }
}());
```

**service.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('userService', userService);

    userService.$inject = ['apiUrlFactory', 'myValue'];

    function userService(apiUrlFactory, myValue) {

        var self = this;

        self.login = function () {
            console.log('myValue', myValue);
            console.log('loginUrl', apiUrlFactory.url);
        };

        return self;

    }
}());
```

If you have more questions, do not hesitate to contact with me. Also try angular style guide https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide It will help you a lot.

Comment: when I use same module name not working for me why ?

Comment: @nuruddin could you create plunkr, It will be easier to help you